# Rename datatype "No instance … arising from the literal"

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and trying to explore how datatypes in Haskell work. For instance, I'm trying to run the following code:

```hs
data Number = Int
num :: Number
num = 1
```

However with that, I get the following error:

```
main.hs:3:7: error:
    * No instance for (Num Number) arising from the literal `1'
    * In the expression: 1
      In an equation for `num': num = 1
  |
3 | num = 1
  |
```

**Why am I getting that error when `1` should be an `Int`?**

For reference, I come from a TypeScript and Rust background where you can do similar things:

```js
// TypeScript
type Num = number // the Number type is already defined
let num: Num = 1
```

```rust
// Rust
type Number = usize;
let num: Number = 1;
```

Comment: `data T = V` means that type `T` has only one value, named `V`. You chose `Int` as a name for that unique value, but that does not refer at all to the `Int` type. By contrast `type T1 = T2` instead means that `T1` is defined as type `T2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a type `Number` that has one data constructor without a parameter. What you likely want to do is construct a *type alias* with:

```
type Number = Int

num :: Number
num = 1
```

Here both `Number` and `Int` are different aliasses for the same type.